# animated symbol is not shown on googlemap

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i want to animate a "car.png" symbol on googlemap but i cant. this is my code

```
var line;

function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(20.291, 153.027),
zoom: 6,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);

var lineCoordinates = [
new google.maps.LatLng(22.291, 153.027),
new google.maps.LatLng(18.291, 153.027)
];

// Define the symbol, using one of the predefined paths ('CIRCLE')
// supplied by the Google Maps JavaScript API.
var lineSymbol = {
path: 'images/car.png',
scale: 8,
strokeColor: '#393'
};
line = new google.maps.Polyline({
path: lineCoordinates,
icons: [{
  icon: lineSymbol,
  offset: '100%'
}],
map: map
 });

animateCircle();
}

function animateCircle() {
var count = 0;
window.setInterval(function() {
  count = (count + 1) % 200;

  var icons = line.get('icons');
  icons[0].offset = (count / 2) + '%';
  line.set('icons', icons);
 }, 20);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

what i should change to work?
i want the car symbol move and the center of map change with it to show the symbol every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are using expects an [SVG symbol](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols), you are using an image (car.png)

```
// Define the symbol
var lineSymbol = {
path: "M-20,0a20,20 0 1,0 40,0a20,20 0 1,0 -40,0",
fillColor: '#FF0000',
fillOpacity: .6,
anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
scale: .8,
strokeColor: '#393'
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gnqcattp/1/

Comment: Thanks. is there anyway to use image instead svg symbol to animate?

Comment: Do something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_animateMarker_linkto.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/julieta.kml) or [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_animate_marker_xml.html) but with a custom icon.